# Kohana 3 How to render module inside application

Tags: php, module, kohana, kohana-3

How to integrate module inside application? I have modules having two controllers and two respective views inside module. Now I want to integrate this module inside my application, so that views and actions can be handled by this module only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have created the module enable it in the application bootstrap.php then you should be able to visit [your-website]/modualController/action you might need to look at routes.

This is a great resource for modules and routing, and everything else Kohana http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php

Comment: Thanks Koorb. Yes It need to be handled by routes.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your Application, modules and System files may intersect. Use this picture to understand [Kohana cascading filesystem](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/about.filesystem):

[image]

So, if both application and your module have a views/welcome.php, application one will be found. When two modules have files with the same path, Kohana will select module with highest position in Kohana::modules() list.